# Sqlite says "no such table" but eventually displays the data from the said table

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite

Let me explain the title. I have this code to check if the table already exists:

```
NSString *checkSql = @"SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='files'";
NSArray *checkArray = [sqlite executeQuery:checkSql];
if ([checkArray count] != 0)
{
   //rest of code here...
   NSLog(@"Files table exists");
}
else
{
   NSLog(@"Files table not found");
}
```

Now, this will always display `Files table exists`. However, when I added these codes:

```
NSArray *selArr = [sqlite executeQuery:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT FileID, FileName, FilePath FROM files WHERE UserID=%@", userId]];
```

This will display this error:`SQLite Prepare Failed: no such table: files
2012-09-17 14:56:35.723 iskoolme[3275:15203]  - Query: SELECT FileID, FileName, FilePath FROM files WHERE UserID=5`.

I don't really understand why it happens. It is not really a problem, because it actually displays the data from the database. I am just curious on what could possibly be the reason for the "error".

Comment: have you copied your database file in your nsdocuments directory?

Comment: yep. In fact everything is actually working, its just so confusing why the "error" comes up when it is clear that the table exists (I mean the data is displayed FROM the table). I am starting to think it is some kind of a bug.